# ZF2 - How can i call a function of a custom class php from a view?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i've created a custom service as php class ( ServiceClass ) with some functions ( generateInfo() )  and i'm looking for a way to call this function from other views

thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own View Helper

```
namespace MyModule\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class MyHelper extends AbstractHelper
{       
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function render($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        return 'My Parametrizable Html ' . $arg1 . ' ' . $arg2;
    }

    public function generateInfo()
    {
        return 'Your HTML goes here';
    }
}
```

Now create an entry in the module.config.php for that helper:

```
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'myHelper' => 'MyModule\View\Helper\MyHelper',
    ),
),
```

And now you can call it in your views:

```
<?php echo $this->myHelper()->render($arg1, $arg2); ?>
```

And for calling the generateInfo():

```
<?php echo $this->myHelper()->generateInfo(); ?>
```

You can also call it from a controller:

```
$viewHelperManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager');
$myHelper = $viewHelperManager->get('myHelper');
```

**Without View Helper**

Not the best practice because this generates repeated code but, if you do not want to create a View Helper, then you can always create an instance of your service in a controller and then pass it to the View.

Comment: thanks for your reply , however there isn't a simplest other way ?

Comment: That is not hard to do and is the best practice. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oh i have last question , how can i call the same function from an action of a controller ?? i don't want to repeat the same peace of code ... i wanna reuse it.....

Comment: do you mean having it as a view helper? I have updated my answer to show you how to call it from a controller

Comment: I got this error : Zend\View\HelperPluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for myHelper

Comment: did you add your helper to your module.config.php?

Comment: yeah i did add it , but can't call other functions instead of the __invokde() function.... what is wrong ?

Comment: I completely changed the helper to allow multiple methods