# How to call controller function in view in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need to call a controller function in my view and passing parameter. I tried to following this [How to call controller function in view in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971421/how-to-call-controller-function-in-view-in-zend-framework) but it's still not working.

I have record from my database like this :

```
---------------
| name  | age |
---------------
| Josh  | 22  |
| Bush  | 43  |
| Rush  | 23  |
---------------
```

here's my index.phtml

```
foreach ($result as $rstd){
    echo "<td>".$this->escapeHtml($rstd['name'])."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$this->escapeHtml($rstd['age'])."</td>";

    //here i want to access my controller function with sending parameter by name and also display something which has i set in that function.
    echo "<td>** result from that function **</td>";
}
```

here's my controller :

```
public function indexAction(){
    $result = $sd->getAllRecord($this->getMysqlAdapter());
    return new ViewModel(array('result'=>$result));
}

public function getRecordByName($name){
    if($name=='Bush'){
        $result = "You'r Old";  
    }else{
        $result = "You'r Young";    
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And i want display it like this :

```
-----------------------------
| name  | age | status      |
-----------------------------
| Josh  | 22  | You'r Young |
| Bush  | 43  | You'r Old   |
| Rush  | 32  | You'r Young |
-----------------------------
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: whatever you have done in `getRecordByName` if you want to do the same you can do it in views directly. but it seems you are looking to write some common functions that you could use in views ?

Comment: and why you believe that Zend 1 solution will work for Zend Framework 2 ? Also that wash half baked solution as its recommended to make view helper then pass whole controller object)

Comment: @Richie yeah, getRecordByName just a simple example . Actually I would make something complex in that function. And i can't do the same in view coz it's so difficult to implements, and it's can be work only in controller not in view.  So do you have a solution for this ..?

Comment: zend 3 question: How can we fetch cms pages title and their links to display them in header / footer sections of entire website. Pages title and links are stored in database. Please share any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments you need to implement viewhelpers 
I have found a very easy solution here. This might be useful for you too.

[ZF2 - How can i call a function of a custom class php from a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815947/zf2-how-can-i-call-a-function-of-a-custom-class-php-from-a-view)

and here

https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/zend-framework-2-create-your-custom-view-helper/

Answer (score 2):

Call a controller action in view in considered **bad practice**. But you could achieve that by using view helpers. So what you need is:

- Create your custom View Helper,
- Register the view helper in invokables in your `module.config.php`,
- Then you could call any controller action in your views

Here is a helper that you could use :

```
class Action extends \Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper implements   ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{

    protected $serviceLocator;
    
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
    public function __invoke($controllerName, $actionName, $params = array())
    {
        $controllerLoader = $this->serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('ControllerLoader');
        $controllerLoader->setInvokableClass($controllerName, $controllerName);
        $controller = $controllerLoader->get($controllerName);
        return $controller->$actionName($params);
    }
}
```

module.config.php :

```
'view_helpers' => array(
'invokables' => array(
    'action' => 'module_name\View\Helper\Action',
),  
),
```

In your view file :

```
$this->action('Your\Controller', 'getRecordByNameAction');
```

Comment: zend 3 question: How can we fetch cms pages title and their links to display them in header / footer sections of entire website. Pages title and links are stored in database. Please share any suggestion. Thanks.